# combinatorial optimization - argmax binary vector

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, discrete-optimization

I have the following combinatorial optimization problem:
$$
\arg\max_{\mathbf{x}} \frac{\alpha + \mathbf{t}\cdot\mathbf{x}}{\beta + \mathbf{f}\cdot\mathbf{x}}
$$
where the objective is to find the $n$ length binary vector $\mathbf{x}\in\{0,1\}^n$ which maximizes the above objective. The objective function has a non-negative integer $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}^*$; and another scalar $\beta \in \mathbb{N}$; and $n$ length vectors $\mathbf{t}, \mathbf{f} \in \mathbb{N}^n$.

Here the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,...\}$, and $\mathbb{Z}^* = \{0,1,2,...\} = \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$.

I am sort of lost what combinatorial optimization this problem is similar to - the closest one I can think of is the knapsack problem. Does anybody know how to solve this or where to look?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry I should have made that clear.

Comment: I'm guessing that this has a solution that can be found in quasi-linear time, and that the discrete (binary) optimum agrees with the continuous $\mathbf x \in [0,1]^n$ optimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with $\mathbf x=0$, sort the pairs $(t_i,f_i)$ in descending order of $t_i/f_i$, and then turn on ones in $\mathbf x$ as long as $t_i/f_i$ is greater than the quotient attained so far.

Comment: Thanks @joriki :) Is there a proof that this solution would be optimal?

Comment: @ahmadh: Yes. At the end of the procedure, there is a one in $\mathbf x$ if and only if the corresponding ratio $t_i/f_i$ is greater than the quotient attained (since the quotient can't exceed the ratio for the one we added last, which was the one with the lowest ratio that we added). Any other value of $\mathbf x$ differs by having ones for some values of $t_i/f_i$ below the quotient and/or zeros for some values of $t_i/f_i$ above the quotient. But adding those pairs with lower values and removing those pairs with higher ratios would lower the quotient.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks :)